# Picasa-like icon manager/organizer for OS X

Tags: macos, icons, organizer-software

I'm looking for a program (preferably free) that will allow me to manage, organize, tag, etc. my collection of icons (in [ICNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format) format).  Something similar to what Picasa and iPhoto do for normal pictures.  Does anyone know of such an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CandyBar](https://www.panic.com/candybar/) is an excellent paid application that organizes icons and includes system icon customization. I'm not aware of any free application that comes close to its functionality.

Comment: It's written on the website, but to make it clearer: The "icon management" part of CandyBar was originally the separate application [pixadex](http://iconfactory.com/software/pixadex) by The Icon Factory.